# adding movieclips from random generated no in array

Tags: actionscript-3

hey i am trying to add movie clips to the stage randomly from a list of cards, no 1- 10, 
this is what i have tried so far but i get an error saying its my randomly selected card is not a function, just wondering if anybody can help or know the proper way of accomplishing it
thank you

```
var printArray:Array =new Array();
var randPrint:String;

var rand
 for(var n:int = 1; n <= 28; n++)
 {
    randNo=Math.round(Math.random() * 10+.5);
    randPrint = "cardPrint"+randNo;
    printArray.push(randPrint);
 }

 var cardPrint1:MovieClip = new card_1();
 var cardPrint2:MovieClip = new card_2();
 var cardPrint3:MovieClip = new card_3();
 var cardPrint4:MovieClip = new card_4();
 var cardPrint5:MovieClip = new card_5();
 var cardPrint6:MovieClip = new card_6();
 var cardPrint7:MovieClip = new card_7();
 var cardPrint8:MovieClip = new card_8();
 var cardPrint9:MovieClip = new card_9();
 var cardPrint10:MovieClip = new card_10();



 for(var p:int = 1; p <= 1; p++)
        {

            trace(printArray[p]);
            addChild(printArray[p]);

        }
```

some help would be great, thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like the following will do what you want. I populated an array with all the available assets and then filled an array with random numbers between 0-9. The last for loop just creates the movieclips and adds them to the stage.

```
var printArray:Array = [];

var mcs:Array = [card_1, card_2, card_3, card_4, card_5, card_6, card_7, card_8, card_9, card_10];

for(var n:int = 1; n <= 28; n++)
{
    var randNo:int = int(Math.random() * 10);
    printArray.push(randNo);
}

for(var p:int = 0; p < printArray.length; p++)
{
    trace(printArray[p]);
    var mc:MovieClip = new mcs[printArray[p]];
    addChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: that is perfect, thank you so much, ive been bashing my head against it for a while, just getting started with as3, thank you so much